# Memory Buffer pool taken by a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My server has 250 GB RAM and it's a physical server. Max memory configured to 230 GB when ran a DMV sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors with joining other DMV, I found a table taking almost 50 GB Buffer pool space. My question is, Is this an Issue? If so what's the best way to tackle it? My PLE is very high, no slowness report. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The data most often and recently used will remain buffer pool cache so it is expected that 50GB of table data will be cached when the table and data are used often. Since your PLE is acceptable, there may be no concerns for now.

You may still want to take a look at query plans that use the table in question. It could be that more data than needed is brought into the buffer pool cache due to large scans when fewer pages are actually needed by queries. Query and index tuning may be in order in that case. Tuning will also reduce CPU and other resource utilization, providing headroom for growth and other queries in the workload.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your reply. So what's the best way (query) to find which query against the table causing this?

Comment: @user3625272, one way is to mine the [proc cache or query store](https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/24/how-to-find-queries-using-an-index-and-queries-using-index-hints/) for indexes on the table(s). Be aware that the queries can be resource intensive though so run judiciously on a production system.